# Extjs Cloning a panel

Tags: extjs, extjs3

panel({}) and all its contents like grid, form and want to render that exact clone to another panel is there a way to do it..is it possible to do it with panel.getEl() or is there any other way...please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must admit that the old answer was not entirely correct. Cloning of Componments is available since ExtJS2 and can be done via `cloneConfig(overrides)` which is a instance-method.

This will return a clone of the current instance with the applied overrides (if set). A clean clone will require you to use correct configurations, meaning no instances are created within the config. [Here are some information bout this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14492179/701988) For more details read the [Sencha guides](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide)

---

**Old answer** *(only valid if the components to clone configs contains instances instead of plain configurations)*

<s>No, there is no buildin way to do this. And you should not try it. Consider to wrap the panel in a function that returns a instance of it (a simple sort of factory).</s>

Edit

Something like this:

```
Factory.Panel = function (config) {
    var defaults = {
        labelWidth: 80,
        labelAlign: 'left',
        layout: 'form',
        width: 720,
        autoHeight: true,
        header: false,
        bodyStyle: 'padding:10px 15px;'
    };
    var cfg = Ext.apply({}, config, defaults);
    var cmp = new Panel(cfg);
    return cmp;
}
```

You can add as much function params as you like. This would be a clean way to do it. You just can clone simple object like a record. Note that Factory is a Namespace!

Comment: hi what u do mean the instance of a panel..will it also include the contents of the panel..can u explain alittle more please even a small example would be helpful..thank u

Comment: hi..i tried u r example but it onle seems to clone the panel alone what about the items in the panel..how do i clone those..

Comment: To clarify one thing; you don't really clone, this is much more a factory. I you have more items nested, that I do not know you need to include them either in a own 'factory' that is called by the other or need to implement them as 'xtypes' so that ExtJS can process them.

Answer (score 8):

The sra's answer is incorrect.  Ext's cloneConfig does exactly what you want it to.  http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-cloneConfig

The following code renders two of the "same" panels to the body.

```
var panel = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
    width: 500,
    height: 300,
    title: "HBoxLayout Panel",
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
    renderTo: document.body,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: 'Inner Panel One',
        flex: 2
    },{
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: 'Inner Panel Two',
        flex: 1
    },{
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: 'Inner Panel Three',
        flex: 1
    }]
});

var clone = panel.cloneConfig();
```

Comment: @sra `Clone the current component using the original config values passed into this instance by default.

Available since: Ext 2`