# Unable to call method in ExtJS class from inside the class

Tags: extjs

When I try to execute the code below, I get two `Uncaught ReferenceError` messages

```
Ext.define('Example.foo', {
  store: _createStore(),
  _createStore: function() {
    return new Ext.data.JsonStore({...});
  }
});
var example = new Example.foo();
```

The error messages:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: _createStore is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: Example is not defined
```

The error still occurs if `_createStore` is defined above `store`. I'm using ExtJS 4.2.1.883.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Foo is some UI component and you must use a function to get a reference to your store, you could do this:

```
Ext.define('Example.Foo', {

    // set other Foo properties...

    initComponent: function () {
        this.store = this.createStore();
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },

    createStore: function () {
        return Ext.create("Ext.data.JsonStore", {
            // store setup
        });
    } 

});
```

If you have a class that represents your store, though, you could just use the string name of the store class and the Ext framework will create an instance of it for you:

```
store: 'Example.stores.FooStore'
```

Comment: Awesome, calling it from `initComponent` is what I needed. A bit of googling lead me to [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492179/to-initcomponent-or-not-to-initcomponent) that explains why it worked.