# Config or InitComponent

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

After reading these two answers ([answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14535598/2481114), [answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14492347/2481114)) I understood to don't add class instances or critical object instances to class definitions. But I wounder where would I use `config`? Am I right that I would (only) use it, when I need getter and setter for these properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getters and setters could be one reason, however, Sencha Touch and upcoming Ext 5 use config extensively, in Touch it is even mandatory. So better to get used to it.