# Best practice adding KeyMaps to a Viewport

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

what's the best place to create / bind KeyMaps to a Viewport ?

Given a very simple Viewport like this :

```
Ext.define('EmptyTemplate.view.Viewport', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
    requires:[
        'Ext.layout.container.Fit',
        'EmptyTemplate.view.Main'
    ],
    layout: {
        type: 'fit'
    },

    items: [{
        xtype: 'app-main'
    }],

    listeners: {
        afterrender: {
            fn: function(){
                // map one key by key code
                this.keyMap = Ext.create('Ext.util.KeyMap', this.el, {
                    scope: this,
                    key: Ext.EventObject.ENTER,
                    fn: function () {
                        console.log("enter pressed");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Whats the proper way to create KeyMaps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**First some best practice advises:**

If you need to setup your component use

- the `[initComponent][1]` (you should [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492179/to-initcomponent-or-not-to-initcomponent/14535598#14535598) for detailed information),
- the other provided `template methods` and
- in some rare cases the `constructor`.

---

In you case I would use the template method **[afterRender](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-afterRender)**

```
Ext.define('EmptyTemplate.view.Viewport', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
    requires:[
        'Ext.layout.container.Fit',
        'EmptyTemplate.view.Main'
    ],
    layout: {
        type: 'fit'
    },

    items: [{
        xtype: 'app-main'
    }],

    afterRender: {
        this.callParent(arguments); // always!!
        this.bindKeyMap();
    },

    bindKeyMap: function() {
        var me = this; // use 'me' if 'this' occurs more then 3 times
        if(me.keyMap) {
            me.keyMap.enable();
            return;
        }
        // map one key by key code
        me.keyMap = Ext.create('Ext.util.KeyMap', me.el, {
            scope: me,
            key: Ext.EventObject.ENTER,
            fn: me.onEnter
        });
    },

    unbindKeyMap: function() {
        this.keyMap.disable();
    },

    onDisable: function() {
        this.unbindKeyMap();
        this.callParent(arguments); // always!!
    },

    onEnable: function() {
        this.callParent(arguments); // always!!
        this.bindKeyMap();
    },

    onEnter: function(){
       // i am executed in the scope of the class instance
    }
});
```

Note that the example above handles the whole keymap but you can also **[add](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.util.KeyMap-method-addBinding)** / **[remove](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.util.KeyMap-method-removeBinding)** single keys from the map.

> **Note** that this is untested prototype code, but it should work this way.

---

**How to find template methods**:

1. Go to the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/)
2. Show protected member

[image]

3. Look for the [image] mark

[image]

[This post about overriding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254321/best-practice-for-overriding-classes-properties-in-extjs/14254627#14254627) might also be a good reading